# Public Key Encryption vs HSM for storing encryption keys

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, azure-keyvault, amazon-kms

Let's say I have sensitive data in the database server that needs to be encrypted (i.e emails, etc..) and I want to make sure that in the event that the server is compromised, the attacker shouldn't be able to decrypt these data (at the very least make it harder).

I've read some solutions online, and it seems like I can either

Use Hardware Security Modules (i.e. Amazon KMS/Vault) to having a separate server handle encryption/decryption.
Use Public Key Encryption (where the public key in database server encrypts data, and a private key is stored in separate server that solely handles decryption)
What are the tradeoffs of each other and which one would you choose?

Comment: Hardware Security Modules and Public Key Encryption can actually work together. Public key encryption refers to asymmetric keys, which can be placed on an HSM.